# Wordpress MYSQL Admin area error - mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'WordPressUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Update: Turns out it was 2 backup plugins that I installed that were interfering with each other.**

This error comes up whenever I try and access the backend. Logging in is not possible and returns an error: `mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'WordPressUser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I've tried:

- Editing my wp-config.php file in my WordPress directory to see if my database credentials are incorrect or not. The credentials work fine and connect, otherwise the main site wouldn't work and logging in wouldn't be possible.
- Setting the permissions of the WordPress directory to www-data:www-data.

This happened when I transferred the website from one machine to the other, but the database schema and domain didn't change. Neither did the OS (I run WordPress on Ubuntu 20.04).
First I transferred the files, which went fine without any errors/difficulties. Then I transferred the database over, which made this error occur.

I've tried turning debug mode on to see if I can find any other errors, the mysqli_real... error is the only one that comes up.

Comment: _"First I transferred the files, which worked fine and could login easily"_ - How could it work before you had transferred the database?

Comment: This is a permission problem in MySQL databases. Do you need modify the MySQL privileges. Set all privileges.

Comment: First of all try to login to MySQL with password you set in the wp-config.php

$ mysql --host=localhost --user=WordPressUser --password=WordPressPass WordPressDBName

Comment: @MohammadZarei My user name isn't 'WordPressUser' which is quite strange, it's something else. The site is returning a different user name then what I've specified in the file.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I set up a new WordPress installation on my separate machine, and then slowly transferred everything over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind! I solved it! It turns out there was a corrupt plugin installed; I tried looking for a backup plugin when I was on my original host and ended up installing several different ones. For some reason, one plugin stored my database username in the database, which was different when I transferred it over. So when I accessed the admin area, that error came up, which was from that plugin.
(I used the 'search' feature in PHPMyAdmin to search the whole database for 'WordPressUser' and found it)

So I deleted the plugin from the WordPress files and deleted the row from my database, and that seemed to solve the problem.